# Read values from URL with python

Tags: python

i try to read values from a IP Adress, the only what is on that page(also in source) are two values comma separated for example: 22.1,17.4,

When i try to read the line with my code:

```html
    def __init__(self, engine, config_dict):
        super(ds18b20, self).__init__(engine, config_dict)
        d = config_dict.get('PondService', {})
        self.filename = d.get(urllib2.urlopen("http://192.168.0.70").read())
        syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_INFO, "ds18b20: using %s" % self.filename)
        self.bind(weewx.NEW_ARCHIVE_RECORD, self.read_file)
```

i get the error:

```
cannot read value: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

what do i need to get the values correct?

Comment: Have you tried debugging? For example, check what the `urllib2.urlopen` call returns.

Comment: no i have no idea to debug this. I thought it was easy when only 2 values on the site, but it isnt :)

Comment: This is for my weewx weather station, i try to look on the output from the syslog. but there is only this error message.

Comment: Check that `urlopen` can access the webpage and that the result matches what you are expecting to find there. Anyway, you'll need to provide more information (like the entire stack trace) for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: so you think the code is correct, and the values do not to be converted?

Comment: Ah OK i have it on my github:https://github.com/Landixus/multipleDS18B20WeeWX/blob/master/ds18b20.py

Comment: Please learn to debug your code. I have already given you some hints on what could be wrong with your application.

Comment: thanks but i am not able to do this. I try to fin another solution or answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok i can now read my values. It looks weird but it works:

```
class ds18b20(StdService):
def __init__(self, engine, config_dict):
    super(ds18b20, self).__init__(engine, config_dict)
    d = config_dict.get('PondService', {})
    url = 'http://192.168.0.70'
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    html_content = page.read()
    rendered_content = html2text.html2text(html_content)
    file = open('/home/weewx/public_html/data/ds18b20.txt', 'w')
    file.write(rendered_content)
    file.close()
    self.filename = d.get('filename', '/home/weewx/public_html/data/ds18b20.txt')
    syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_INFO, "ds18b20: using %s" % self.filename)
    self.bind(weewx.NEW_ARCHIVE_RECORD, self.read_file)

def read_file(self, event):
    try:
        with open(self.filename) as f:
            #value = f.read()
            line = f.readline()
```

BUT, what can i do when the source of the url are not available? 
I think about a delay of 5 minutes then the script try again request.

When i do with:

```html
    import requests

url = 'http://192.160.0.70'
r = requests.get(url)

text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(r.text)
text_file.close()
```

and the source is not available, the script is terminatig.
How can i prevent this?